# Stanford NLP 3.9.0: Does using CoreEntityMention combine adjacent entity mentions?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am testing out getting entity mentions the new 3.9.0 way with CoreEntityMention.  I do something like:

```
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(text);
    stanfordPipe = createNerPipeline();
    stanfordPipe.annotate(document);

    for (CoreSentence sentence : document.sentences()) {
        logger.debug("Found sentence {}", sentence);
        if (sentence.entityMentions() == null) continue;
        for (CoreEntityMention cem : sentence.entityMentions()) {
            logger.debug("Found em {}", stringify(cem));            
        }
    }
```

When I iterate through entity mentions using `sentence.entityMentions()` I see that some of the entity mentions produced are multi-token entity mentions.  The old way of getting entity mentions, and correct me if I am wrong, is that you have to iterate over CoreLabel and therefore have to combine the multi-token entity mentions yourself.

So is there some new method that did not exist before to combine adjacent tokens with the same ner label?  Or have I missed older ways to combine multi-token entity mentions?

Comment: Ok, I see that the code is a wrapper around the `CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class` contained in the `CoreMap` representing the sentence.  I still need to look at that because I have very special cases that are not easy to capture when combining mentions.

Comment: The example code on the Stanford pages though shows the CoreLabel approach as the way to get the ner annotations from a document though so it would be nice to have that way documented as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi thanks for using the new interface!

Yes, the CoreEntityMention is supposed to represent a full entity mention.  This was some new syntax added to help make it easier to work with our code.

Traditionally there has been a need for things like sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)...etc...so we tried to add some wrapper classes so people could use the pipeline interface but not have the cumbersome syntax.

With this newly debuted syntax, you can write:

```
sentence.tokens();
```

Regarding entity mentions, if the sentence is "Joe Smith went to Hawaii." you would get two entity mentions:

Joe Smith  (2 tokens)
Hawaii (1 token)

Traditionally the `ner` annotator would tag every token in the sentence with it's named entity type.  Then a separate `entitymentions` annotator would build `Mention` annotations which were `CoreMap` representations of full entity mentions (e.g. Joe Smith).

I've seen a lot of people over the years ask "How do I go from a tagged sequence of tokens to the full entity mentions?"  So in response to this we tried to make it a lot easier to just extract the full entity's referred to in the sentence.

I should also note that for the most part the older ways should still work.  Updated documentation is on the way as we work on finalizing the 3.9.0 release!

Comment: And maybe to elaborate some more, if you want to combine the tokens into entity mentions that is still possible, as the tokens contain the named entity info.  But traditionally in say version 3.8.0, you could use the entitymentions annotator and it would combine them into entity mentions.

Comment: Wow, what a great response!  I never really knew about the EntityMentions annotator until I dug into 3.9 because it is not clearly documented that one can do that via the pipeline and I ask for greater documentation.  In combining entity mentions, I do have some nasty cases that I have to explore myself to see if EntityMentions would work (and that is why I am satisfied to have custom combining for now).  For example, what happens if ` or - are present in the middle of the entity mention (like Baskin-Robbins).  Would cases like that be combined because - would likely have NER tag of O?

Comment: If "Baskin" "-" "Robbins" is identified as an ORG, it should have (ORG,ORG,ORG) from NER, and it would be correctly captured as an entity mention.  If you had (ORG, O, ORG) for that, that is a failure of NER, not the entity mention collection technique.

Comment: Also, I just wrote up some new documentation for this new API, and will be posting it soon.