# With the Simple API in Stanford CoreNLP, is there a way to get multi-token entity mentions?

Tags: stanford-nlp

This question is very similar to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632256/stanford-nlp-3-9-0-does-using-coreentitymention-combine-adjacent-entity-mention), however due to the way SO works, I think it is better to ask a new question rather than just continue a thread.

CoreNLP has the [Simple API](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html) which allows for quicker access to various components of the NLP pipeline.  The way to get named entities appears to be:

1. Form a document annotation from the text
2. Get the sentences from the document object
3. Use `nerTags()` from the sentences object to get the token-by-token ner labeling.

Via other mechanisms, as talked about in the question link above, one can retrieve full multi-token entity mentions such as George Washington, which is an entity mention composed of 2 tokens.  Is there a way using the simple api to get these multi-token entity mentions?

Comment: Don't reference other questions. Make sure your question can stand by itself, all relevant information needs to be directly in your own question. Also, you question is probably too broad anyway

Comment: @musefan.  It is its own question and it is very specific.  Either it can be done or not.

Comment: So if I edit out all the references to the question you linked, it would still make sense would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it gives you less information than the full API, returning only the String spans of the mention. See [`Sentence#mentions(String)`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/91d520a46042d26ed91bff4562056f7584829984/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.java#L567) and [`Sentence#mentions()`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/91d520a46042d26ed91bff4562056f7584829984/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.java#L598).

If you want to get more information about a mention, you'll have to either use the regular API, or re-implement the logic in these functions. You can also try mucking around in [the raw Proto](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/91d520a46042d26ed91bff4562056f7584829984/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.java#L307), which will certainly have all the information you could possibly want, but in a less-than-pleasant proto interface. The proto definition is [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/91d520a46042d26ed91bff4562056f7584829984/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/CoreNLP.proto).

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed to know.  I think my preferred approach is to use the 3.9 mechanism to get the MentionsAnnotation objects, however one particular project I am working with is currently only on 3.8 and so it is nice for me to know the 3 different ways.